# Getting Json data using jQuery Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to get some data from a Google API that I have found. The trouble is i can find no documentation for this ASP (it must be a secret one). For some reason i am unable to pull the JSON data from the following link.

```
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1GBP=?USD&callback=?
```

My error is shown in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/FzLPC/)

I am getting the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculator API doesn't return valid JSON. The labels are not quoted so it can't be directly parsed. The only thing you can do is try to manually add the quotes to the labels before letting jQuery parse the JSON. This would make it valid.

```
{lhs: "1 British pound",rhs: "1.5637 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}
 ^ no quotes
```

Below is a quick and dirty solution that replaces each label with itself and adds the quotes. This is not very robust because each of the labels are hard coded but it should give you the right idea.

```
        var data = '{lhs: "1 British pound",rhs: "1.5637 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}';            
             data = data.replace('lhs:', '"lhs":');
             data = data.replace('rhs:', '"rhs":');
             data = data.replace('error:', '"error":');
             data = data.replace('icc:', '"icc":');

            data = JSON.parse(data);

            for(i in data) {
                content = data[i];
                $("#data-list").append(content.text + "<hr />");
            }
```

To get around the same origin policy, I would proxy the API request through a server side script on the same domain.

jQuery supports JSONP but the problem is jQuery will try to parse the JSON before we get to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this still doesnt seem to be working. When testing in JSFiddle I am getting the following error: "Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Yeah it won't work because of the cross domain request. I would proxy the request through a server side script e.g PHP or ASP. So your ajax calls the server side, the server does the API request, and passes back to Javascript. This would get around the cross origin policy